# How can I delete all the rows where the value of columnA is equal to the value of columnB in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I delete all the rows where the value of columnA is equal to the value of columnB in excel? I found some articles but they are all talking about deleting rows with some conditions for one row (then i can use filter in excel to get the rows). But how can I filter rows where the condition needs values from two columns? thanks.

like if i have

```
Row columnA columnB
1    10     10
2    20     20
3    30     40
4    50     70
```

then I want to keep row 3 and row4 and delete row 1 and row2 because they have the same value for columnA and columnB

Comment: Formulas cannot "delete".  It would help if you would show sample data of what you have and the expected output.

Comment: @ScottCraner. thanks. Just updated

Comment: You still say "Delete". Formula do not change the values to which they reference.  Do  you instead want to return the values where A and B are not equal in another location?

Comment: @ScottCraner. Yea, that should work. it can generate a new tab/sheet with all the rows where A != B and i can continue working on the new sheet/tab

Answer (score 2):

**OPTION 1**

Something like this in an adjacent column?

```
=FILTER(A:B,A:A<>B:B,"")
```

It will reproduce column A without the duplicates.

[image: Example]

**OPTION 2**

If you are looking for a way to quickly distinguish where the rows match and do not match (based on your comment) I would suggest a conditional format using the following:

```
=$A1<>$B1
```

[image: Conditional Format]

**OPTION 3**

Or utilize the formula in cell C1:

```
=IF(A:A<>B:B,"Not Equal","")
```

[image: Example 3]

Comment: Thanks Kevin, i am new to excel. So this will generate a column C? and i can delete all the rows where column C is not blank?

Comment: Yes, just pasting this formula in C1 (as shown in the image) will automatically create the array for all values returned. However, what exactly do you mean by delete the rows where Column C is not blank? The above formula will return every value in Column A that does NOT equal the corresponding value in Column B.

Comment: because I want to delete all the rows where A!=B.. in this case, how can I know which rows I should delete?

Comment: Check out the updated post, perhaps if you are not concerned with it looking pretty or being heavily utilized you can go with Option 3. It will essentially insert the text "Not Equal" in the rows where the values do not match.

Comment: Option3 looks good, but it did not work for me.. should i put the formula in `Formulas` tab?

Comment: You should be able to select the cell and paste it in as the value. No different than how you enter text except it will contain an "=" sign. What exactly is happening when you say it doesn't work?