# Get all the rows meeting certain conditions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have below sample data in excel:

```
Row ColA ColB
1   10   10
2   0    10
3   50   0
4   70   70
5   0    0
```

I would like to keep all the rows where A != 0 AND A !=B. In my example, I need to only keep row 3. I need to delete row 1 and row4 because A = B. I need to delete row 2 and row5 because A = 0.
from previous research, the easiest way is to use a new column (say colC) and mark colC "delete" for rows meeting condition `A = 0 or A = B`. Then delete all the rows where colC has "delete". What's the easier way to do so? I tried formula but didn't work for me. Tried VBA but didn't work either (I might be using them wrongly as I am new to Excel).Thanks!

Comment: Was this your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74881064/how-can-i-delete-all-the-rows-where-the-value-of-columna-is-equal-to-the-value-o?noredirect=1#comment132147236_74881064 ?  If so how did you try to manipulate that to do what you want here?  The documentation show how to do multiple: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

Comment: @ScottCraner Yea, none of the answers worked for me..

Comment: The conditional formatting (from your previous question) is one of the easiest filtering ways (without using helper columns) and works like a charm to filter out the undesired rows imo.

Answer (score 2):

Formula solution to show result as per condition.

```
=FILTER(A2:A6,(A2:A6<>0)*(A2:A6<>B2:B6))
```

[image]

`VBA` solution to delete rows.

```
Sub RemoveMatchRow()
Dim rng As Range, rws As Long, i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
  rws = rng.Rows.Count
  
  For i = rws To 1 Step (-1)
    If (rng.Rows(i) = 0) Or (rng.Rows(i) = rng.Rows(i).Offset(, 1)) Then
        rng.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
  Next
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Harun! if i have 20K records, is there a way to get rid of the hardcoded number? or i have to do something like `=FILTER(A2:A20000,(A2:A20000<>0)*(A2:A20000<>B2:B20000))`? Also, does `*` mean "AND"?

Comment: @code3 Yes, `*` is equivalent of `AND()` operation. Your formula is correct.